# ¿Error al agregar dos condiciones WHERE en una consula MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero mostrar datos mediante dos condiciones `WHERE`, preguntas por categorías y que estas preguntas estén habilitadas al publico.

Realizo lo siguiente:

```
$categoria = "categoria_uno";
$habilitado = "1";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id,pregunta,fecha FROM questions WHERE categoria=? AND WHERE habilitado=? order by id DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("si",$categoria,$habilitado)
```

Pero me muestra un error en la linea: `$stmt->bind_param("si",$categoria,$habilitado)`

Mostrándome lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `bind_param()` on boolean

Porque el error, que otro parámetro debo pasar en `WHERE categoria=? AND WHERE habilitado=?`

Comment: @Alfredo He trabajado siempre con las comillas, nunca me ejecuto errores por eso, en la respuesta que me acaban de dar soluciono el error que me ejecutaba gracias.

Comment: que bien te sirvió sin embargoi te dejo esa recomendación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario agregar más de una vez `WHERE`, no es necesario repetirlo por cada condición que desees agregar a la consulta.

Debes quitar el `WHERE` adicional, de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE categoria=? AND habilitado=?
```

Y así sucesivamente si deseas pasarlas más condiciones simplemente añades otro `AND` ejemplo:

```
WHERE categoria=? AND habilitado=? AND otracondicion=? AND otros=?
```

Al final la consulta debe quedar de tal forma:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id,pregunta,fecha FROM questions WHERE categoria=? AND habilitado=? order by id DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 detalles mal:

1. Si el campo de habilitado en tu bind_param() lo marcas como integer, entonces quitale las comillas al valor en la variable
2. quita el where que esta de mas

   `<?php
   $categoria = "categoria_uno";
   $habilitado = 1;
   $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id,pregunta,fecha FROM questions WHERE 
   categoria=? AND habilitado=? order by id DESC");
   $stmt->bind_param("si",$categoria,$habilitado)`

> Debes comprender que si agregas comillas a un valor lo estas
>   transformando a cadena de texto